# PostgreSQL jsonb_array_elements with array of Hash elements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL table (creatures) that looks like the following:

```
| id <integer> | json <jsonb> |
-------------------------------
|      1       | {"name": "Grooper", "weaknesses":[{"type":"Fire", "value":2},{"type":"Dark", "value":2}]} |
|      2       | {"name": "Zik", "weaknesses":[{"type":"Fire", "value":2}]} |
```

I am trying to create a query that filters on weakness type, such that I can filter on all creatures with weaknesses to types `Fire` **or** `Dark` (contain either one), but also query on creatures with weaknesses of type `Fire` **and** `Dark` (must contain both).

I have figured out a query that works with `Fire` **or** `Dark`:

```
select 
  distinct c.* 
from 
  creatures c, 
  jsonb_array_elements(json->'weaknesses') as weakness 
where weakness->'type' ?| array['Fire','Dark']
```

How can I get this query to work to filter on creatures of types `Fire` **and** `Dark`?

UPDATE:

I have a query which seems to accomplish what I want, but it doesn't look pretty. Any tips?

```
SELECT * FROM creatures
WHERE 'Fire' in (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json->'weaknesses')->>'type') 
AND 'Dark' in (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json->'weaknesses')->>'type')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to "look into" the `jsonb` values inside the array so you can't use the `?&` operator. Instead, find the appropriate keys with the `?` operator and select only those rows that have two hits:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, json
FROM creatures
JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(json->'weaknesses') ON value ? 'Dark' OR value ? 'Fire'
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING count(id) = 2;
```

By the way, if `id` is unique (primary key perhaps?) then `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, json ...` is much faster because the `jsonb` document does not have to be examined to remove duplicates.